# Unable to run Activity method in Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, methods, dialog

I am making a hangman game in Android Studio using Java. I have a button "Guess" which opens a dialog that includes an edit text and two buttons. One of the buttons is to confirm the guess so it gets the text entered (`guessedWord`) and compares it to the hangman word (`wordToGuess`). If it's wrong it adds an image and if it's correct the user wins the game. The method to compare the words is in my activity (`GameActivity.java`) but the button press is in my Dialog Fragment (`GuessWord.java`). I am trying to call the method `runGuessWord()` in the Dialog Fragment but I get an error when I click on the confirm button:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.hangman.GameActivity.guessWord()' on a null object reference

I tried using a getter and setter to send the inputted text. Code below:

GameActivity.java

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GuessWord guessWord;
    public int wrongGuesses = 0;
    public String wordToGuess;

    private void openGuessDialog() {
        guessWord = GuessWord.newInstance();
        guessWord.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), GuessWord.TAG);
    }
    public void runGuessWord() {
        GuessWord guessedWordInput = new GuessWord();
        guessedWordInput.setGuessedWord("");
        guessedWord = guessedWordInput.getGuessedWord();

        if (!guessedWord.equals("")) {
            if (guessedWord.equals(wordToGuess)) {
                gameWin();
            } else {
                wrongGuesses += 1;
                setImage();
                if (wrongGuesses == 7) {
                    gameOver();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GuessWord.java:

```
public class GuessWord extends DialogFragment {
    private GameActivity gameActivity;
    public String guessedWord;
    public EditText guessEntered;
    public static final String TAG = "guess";

    public static GuessWord newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        GuessWord fragment = new GuessWord();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_guess, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setCancelable(false);
        closeGuess();
        confirmGuess();
    }

    private void closeGuess() {
        Button closeGuess = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnCloseGuess);
        closeGuess.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dismiss();
        });
    }

    private void confirmGuess() {
        Button confirmGuess = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmGuess);
        EditText guessEntered = getView().findViewById(R.id.etGuess);
        confirmGuess.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            guessedWord = guessEntered.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
            if (guessedWord.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a guess!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                dismiss();
                System.out.println("Text Input = " + guessedWord);
                gameActivity.runGuessWord();
            }
        });
    }

    public String getGuessedWord() {
        return guessedWord;
    }
    public void setGuessedWord(String guessedWord) {
        this.guessedWord = guessedWord;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not assign value for `gameActivity` so it always null. Add it in your DialogFragment

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameActivity = ((GameActivity) getActivity());
    }
```